# mathematica: how to convert string to number (with fortran like "E")?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I like to read a string like "`1.23E4`" in mathematica. I can only find Read to so that but it needs a stream. This works, but seems rather inefficient:

```
StringToNumber[str_] := (strStream = StringToStream[str];
     aNumber = Read[strStream, Number];
     Close[strStream];
     aNumber)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: ``Internal`StringToDouble@"1.23E4"`` yet in general: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38952/5478

Comment: just what i was looking for! thanks